# How to create unique registration number

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get unique admission number for every student. So I am counting number of rows in database and displaying value in student admission number. But if I enter student details and after submission it will be saved in database and when I delete that and if I again want to enter the new student details its taking the same register number which i deleted .I want unique registration numbers. So please help me to get the unique numbers which should not be repeated.

Comment: what is data type of Registration number field?

Answer (score 3):

You can use feature of `AUTO_INCREMENT` property of `MySQL` if you have numeric Registration number field.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a column that is `AUTO_INCREMENT` or you can create a row that is `UNIQUE` and check before inserting

```
CREATE TABLE `reg` (
   `reg_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function this will give random number and also check if its gives a same number again call this function

```
$len = 5;
randID($len);
     function randID($len) {
            $index = "0123456789";
            $out = "";
            for ($t=0; $t<$len;$t++) {
              $r = rand(0,61);
              $out = $out . substr($index,$r,1);
            }
            return $out;
        }
```

Comment: That would be random, but not necessarily unique. You would still have to check a history of all registration numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Auto increment is best way like following

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name (
`reg_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `reg_id` )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a random id and set this in your db:

```
<?php
function RandStr($length, $encrypt = 10){
    $reg_id = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$encrypt;$i++){
        $reg_id = base64_encode(md5(microtime(true)).$str);}
    return substr($reg_id, 0, $length);
}
//Make the REG_ID
echo "REG_ID= ". RandStr(10);
?>
```

Comment: Yes there microtime() a value is that returns "the current" Unix timestamp with "microseconds", returned as md5() hash as a 32-character hexadecimal number and all this data encoded with base64().